# Compare two arrays: one contais sole words, the other contains phrases. some made of those words, some not

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

While I thought it was going to be straightforward as doing a comparison of arrays it is not working as expected. They can only be compared with a regex pattern. 
EXAMPLE of what the two arrays look like:

first array contains lone words like, house, cat, dog etc. The second string contains phrases "I have a house", "i have a cat". So the point is to see what words of first array are contained in the second array that has the phrases

SAMPLE ARRAY WORDS: {house, dog, cat, man, girl, etc}

SAMPLE ARRAY PHRASES: {"I have a house", "I am a dog", "I am man" etc}

I have gone through all the array methods in the documentation here

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html

Is not to use subtraction of arrays to see differences, we are not talking about numbers. It is not to check if some are included because the boolean is not an answer to me and besides,

The bad and strange result that  I am getting is that it prints me out the full of the second array as if everything from the first array was contained there, which is not the case.

I have tried 3 variants, .each, select, and for.

Note: if instead of using a variable I hardcode a string that I know it is part of the second array, it gets me the results fine.  Also, IF I write a variable and I assign it the value by hand such as this: item = house and they put it into the pattern of the regex, it also works! so the problem would seem to be that somehow the items are not being extracted from the first array, but that is not the case because I tried printing them and they print out fine. So, if they are correctly extracted from the first array, and they work if I assign by hand the value of the variable, why can't I just assign automatically the values to the variable as they come out of the first array? that is what drives me insane. 8 hours so far.

The code is not long, only 4 lines, I have included multiple approaches I have tried. 5 actually

TAKE NUMBER ONE:

```
words= Array.new
File.open('mtos-array.txt').each { |line| linesdb << line }
phrases = Array.new
File.open('out23.txt').each { |line| fcia << line }

$x = 0
for item in words do
          for mto in phrases
             if(mto =~/#{item}/)         
             puts"it is contained in #{mto}"                 
             end
          end
        puts $x
        $x +=1

end
```

TAKE NUMBER TWO

```
x = words.select {|num| num}
        phrases.each {|a|
            if(a =~/#{x}/)         
              puts"coincide com #{a}"                 
            end
}
```

THIS THIRD TAKE very compact does not work either. It prints me out the full of the second array (linesdb). I would have wanted to print ONLY if x is contained in v

```
x = words.select {|num| num}
   puts(phrases.select {|v| v =~ /#{x}/})
```

TAKE NUMBER 4

This harcoded value works, only that I need variables instead but insanely cant have them work. To make it even clearer: Suppose  the word house comes from the first array, it indeed finds me all the phrases in the second array that contain the word "house".

```
num = "house"
phrases.each {|a| if(a =~/#{num}/)        
         puts"coincide en #{a}"
     end
}
```

TAKE  NUMBER 5
again it prints me out the full second array

```
for item in words do
phrases.each {|a| if(a =~/#{item}/)        
            puts"it is contained in en #{a}"
            end
            }
end
```

Comment: Without specific examples of what `fcia` and `linesdb` contain and what you expect to be output, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: first array contains lone words likke, house, cat, dog etc. The second string contains phrases "I have a house", "i have a cat". So the point is to see what words of first array are contained in the second array that has the phrases.

Comment: Put in your question _explicit_ examples e.g. `fcia = ["likke", ...]` including an expected output array `output = [...]`

Comment: With array contains as you described (but don't show), it works as expected: https://ideone.com/TP28Lp

Comment: Do not destroy the contents of your questions. Your questions need to remain intact so that they answers continue to make sense. If you have new questions, ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words = ["house", "dog", "cat", "man", "girl"]
phrases = ["I have a house", "I am a dog", "I am man"]

words.select { |word| phrases.any? { |phrase| phrase.include? word } }
 #=> ["house", "dog", "man"]
```

Comment: @Arminius this works for `["I house have", "dog I am", "i man am"]` too.

Comment: If I use the IRB it works,. If I use the ide  and I run it from the console it does not get me the right results. I dont know why